# Помогите разобратсья с lambda

Tags: c#, lambda, openxml

Есть такой код:

```
private static Row GetRow( Worksheet worksheet, uint rowIndex )
{
         return worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().
                     Elements<Row>().Where( r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex ).First();
}
```

Что бы мне его лучше понять я его раскладываю так:

```
SheetData sheetData = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
Row row = sheetData.Elements<Row>().Where( r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex ).First();
```

Но кто мне подскажет как я могу написать выражение:

```
...Where( r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex ).First();
```

Без лямбды? Это вообще возможно, ведь раньше как то это делали?
Я не против лямбд, просто хочу разобраться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда-то давно, во времена C# 1.0, использовали обычные делегаты. Без поддержки замыканий на уровне языка было тяжело, и приходилось писать что-то вроде:

```
class RowIndexFilter
{
    public RowIndexFilter(rowIndex)
    {
        this.RowIndex = rowIndex;
    }

    int RowIndex;

    public bool Filter(Row r)
    {
        return r.RowIndex == this.RowIndex;
    }
}

// объявлен где-то рядом с Where
delegate bool RowFilter(Row r);

// 
....Where(new RowFilter(
             new RowIndexFilter(rowIndex).Filter
                       )
          ).First();
```

C# 2.0 принес с собой вывод типа делегата. Теперь код окончательного вызова чуть сократился

```
// 
....Where(new RowIndexFilter(rowIndex).Filter).First();
```

Но кроме того, C# 2.0 принес с собой анонимные методы и механизм замыканий. Компилятор научился генерировать классы-обертки сам, весь код стал выглядеть вот так:

```
...Where(delegate(Row r) { return r.RowIndex == rowIndex; } ).First();
```

Этот синтаксис появился в 2005-ом году.

Лямбды, добавленные в C# 3.0, не сильно его сократили. Основная фишка лямбд - это возможность компилировать их как в анонимные методы, так и в деревья выражений. А вовсе не для экономии на слове delegate :)

Comment: Видать вы тут не одну собаку съели) Мне сложно привыкнуть после Си к таким выкрутасам и я всегда пытаюсь писать везде обычные циклы, хотя наверное это не очень эффективно..

Comment: 1) выходит что First(); было аж с первой редакции C#? 2) А как вы так вызываете (new RowIndexFilter(rowIndex).Filter).First(); Если Filter это у вас функция к тому же принимающая параметр?

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov стандартного First не было (как и стандартного Where, и вообще механизма метого расширения) - их добавили в C# 3.0. Но самописные библиотеки были.

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov Filter - это метод. Если упоминать его в коде без скобок - `Filter`, а не `Filter()` - то компилятор может создать из него делегат нужного вида. `Where` принимает делегат вида `bool Func(Row r)`, метод подходит туда по параметрам и по возвращаемому значению. Т.е. работает наоборот - не "метод можно использовать вместо лямбды", а "метод, анонимный метод и или лямбду можно использовать там, где ожидается делегат"

Answer (score 4):

Пока писал сам понял сори за тупняк:

```
    Row row;
    foreach(Row currow in sheetData.Elements<Row>() )
    {
        if( currow.RowIndex == rowIndex )
        {
            row = currow;
            break;
        }
    }
```